# How to put the title of the Activity on the right of the toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio

I have written a code to shift the title of the activity to right.The following is the java code.I am using getSupportActionBar().

Here's the [Image of the toolbar I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8OAs.png)

```
   package com.example.hsports.practicesession;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        String getUserEmail = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userEmail");
        String getUserPassword = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userPassword");


        TextView displayUserEmail= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayUserEmail);
        //this.setTitle("Welcome"+" "+getUserEmail);

       // getActionBar().setTitle("Welcome"+" "+getUserEmail);




        TextView displayUserPassword=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayUserPassword);


        displayUserEmail.setText(getUserEmail);
        displayUserPassword.setText(getUserPassword);







        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView welcomeTextView = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
        welcomeTextView.setText("Welcome " + getUserEmail);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And this is the xml code which is for the Homepage.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.hsports.practicesession.HomePage"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_page"

    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

            />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayUserEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayUserPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I actually want the title of the page to come to right of the above action bar.
how to to do this.

The error I am getting is this:

07-14 00:03:03.763 3038-3038/com.example.hsports.practicesession E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.hsports.practicesession, PID: 3038
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hsports.practicesession/com.example.hsports.practicesession.HomePage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.hsports.practicesession.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:46)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Could you please provide screenshot to show what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: are you sure you have an actionbar in the activity? check your `style.xml` and see if you are using one with no actionbar

Comment: also, the actionbar is independent of the view. setting gravity on the xml will not help. you'll have to implement your own custom actionbar

Comment: Yeah I got the solution @MichaelSpitsin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a toolbar in your xml layout, so your xml file should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.hsports.practicesession.HomePage"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_page">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayUserEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayUserPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and then you need to set the `supportActionBar` in the `onCreate` method like this :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

after this you can set the title :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Welcome"+" "+getUserEmail);
```

but in your case you're trying to set the title before you've set the `supportActionBar`, so you're getting `NullPointerException`.

Also, `R.id.toolbar` is not in your current xml layout, so again it'll throw a `NullPointerException`, so change your xml file to add a `Toolbar` as suggested above.

**UPDATE**

To have the text on right :

You need to add your own `TextView` inside the `Toolbar` and then there's no need to set toolbar title like this :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Welcome"+" "+getUserEmail);
```

Change your `activity_home_page.xml` code to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.hsports.practicesession.HomePage">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home_page" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then in your `Activity` do this :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
TextView welcomeTextView = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
welcomeTextView.setText("Welcome " + getUserEmail);
```

**OUTPUT** :

[image]

Comment: I don't want to create a new toolbar. The toolbar which is already there from the android.manifest file , I want the text in it to be present on right side for this activity.

Comment: oh so,can you show some screenshot of the desired output?

Comment: How can send to you the screenshot?

Comment: I have attached the image to the question.

Comment: The "welcome s@y.com" I want it in right side for both the toolbars.

Comment: I will try today and let u know asap.

Comment: I am getting an error and I have edited the question above as per your recommendation. Please have a look. I have edited the error which I got.

Comment: hey @shikher.mishra, you'll have two files : `activity_home_page.xml` and `content_home_page.xml`, change the content of `activity_home_page.xml` as suggested above (under update section of the answer), don't modify the `content_home_page.xml`

Comment: happy to help! you can mark the answer as correct so that others can benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The null object reference is because you are setting the title of the toolbar before you set the toolbar itself. This can be fixed by:

```
    //REMOVED
    TextView displayUserPassword=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayUserPassword);


    displayUserEmail.setText(getUserEmail);
    displayUserPassword.setText(getUserPassword);



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Welcome"+" "+getUserEmail);
```

Comment: but still the the title in the toolbar is not going in the right side.What to do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
 this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Welcome"+" "+getUserEmail);
```

is trying to set the title of an action bar that doesn't exist.

Your app theme may not have an action bar or you are not referencing it properly.