# How to show the App Name in the right side of actionbar in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-actionbar

I'm working on a project in Android Studio with Kotlin language. I want the app name to be on the right side of the actionbar. How is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything to implement actionbar(toolbar)?.

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38335641/2949612